# write a function to associate a type to a distribution function

Tags: function-pointers

**Problem part:**

Write two functions (in "C" language) to cover the following scenario:

INITIALIZATION FUNCTION

This function takes two parameters:  a type name, as a “char *”, and a function pointer (to a user defined “callback” function).   This initialization function stores the association between the type name and the function pointer for later use by the “dispatching” function, defined, below.  (Although you may use a global variable for this storage if an alternative way to store the association is not clear to you, you may also add a third parameter to handle non-global storage.)  This function is called a number of times, once for each type.

DISPATCHING FUNCTION

Given a type name and a “void *” to a variable which is an example of that type, use the associated function, as stored in the above initialization function, by passing the “void *” pointer to the associated function for the given type.  The return from the associated function (as a “void *”) is returned by the dispatching function.

There is a 3rd function type, the user defined (associated) functions, but you are not coding them, for this.

Is this question clear to you?  (Question posted to Note, your questions to me, in Chat..., please.)

It would be best to agree on the data structure initialized by the first, then the prototypes for the two, before trying to code the body of those functions.

**My question part:**

I have explored a lot in function pointers and distribution functions, I think I have already understand both of these two topics, what my question is I don't quite understand the above question, what does it ask me to do? can somebody explain me a little bit so that I can code it up.

Thanks in advance!

Here are some of code I drafted up:

```
typedef char *type;
typedef void (*pt2_dispatch) (void*);


// use a structure to store association
typedef struct{
    type name;
    pt2_dispatch entry;
}dispatch;

dispatch disp_list[N];

dispatch* tmp = disp_list;
void initial_func(type t, pt2_dispatch f){
       tmp.name = t;
       tmp.entry = f;
       tmp++;
}

void* dispatch_func(pt2_dispatch g){

}

// I couldn't get what should I filled in dispatch_func(){...}
```

Comment: Who asked you to create these functions? Maybe you should ask that person?

Comment: it was actually an interview question I encountered, I failed at this question and therefore lost that opportunity but later I did a lot of homework to trying to solve it for my self improvement

Comment: A ok. Hope someone can answer it for you. Good luck.